# How to run missed jobs in Quartz?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have daily cron job, which should run at 00:00 in all time zones, but then app is in maintanance (may be hour or two), the part of scheduled jobs is lost.

Is it possible to run tasks which was missed at maintenance period?

I have configured Quartz with parameters below (`/grails-app/conf/quartz.properties`):

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDS

org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.user = username
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.maxConnections = 20

org.quartz.jdbcStore = true
```

I added `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW` option to trigger ([grails quartz plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/quartz)):

```
class DailyReportJob {

    static triggers = {
        DateTimeZone.availableIDs.each { tzID ->
            cron([
                name: tzID,
                cronExpression: '0 1 0 * * ?',
                timeZone: TimeZone.getTimeZone((String)tzID),
                misfireInstruction: CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW
            ])
        }
    }

    def execute(context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But nothing changes, missed job still not run.

Before Quartz shoutdown (record from `qrtz_triggers`):

```
sched_name     | quartzScheduler
trigger_name   | America/Yakutat
trigger_group  | GRAILS_TRIGGERS
job_name       | myapp.jobs.DailyReportJob
job_group      | GRAILS_JOBS
description    | 
next_fire_time | 1429171260000
prev_fire_time | -1
priority       | 5
trigger_state  | WAITING
trigger_type   | CRON
start_time     | 1429170209000
end_time       | 0
calendar_name  | 
misfire_instr  | 1 
job_data       | \x
```

After Quartz started:

```
sched_name     | quartzScheduler
trigger_name   | America/Yakutat
trigger_group  | GRAILS_TRIGGERS
job_name       | myapp.jobs.DailyReportJob
job_group      | GRAILS_JOBS
description    | 
next_fire_time | 1429257660000
prev_fire_time | -1
priority       | 5
trigger_state  | WAITING
trigger_type   | CRON
start_time     | 1429171539000
end_time       | 0
calendar_name  | 
misfire_instr  | 1
job_data       | \x
```

Comment: I found strange behavior: before checking which tasks is missed, quartz (maybe quartz plugin) remove all records from database and add new.

Comment: Yeah, it's bug of https://grails.org/plugin/quartz

Comment: So I report about bug into
jira: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPQUARTZ-144

Comment: I also found useful article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire

Answer (score 1):

Did your Triggers use the option for "MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW"? Likely, if you're using a CronTrigger, this is the option you want.